# Its gives Heap memory full error for Cassandra database:How to go with limited data for doing iteration

Tags: java, cassandra-2.0

Guide me for Logic

```
for (year) //for list of year
{
    for (month) // month from jan to dec
    {
        for (Zip) // get data for zip in month-year
        {
            for (objlistdata) // all 10000 records
            {
                if ((year == objlistdata.year) && (month == objlistdata.month) && (zip == objlistdata.zip)) {
                    //save obj 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Without _way more_ information it's hard to tell you anything besides: did you acquire and analyze a heap dump to see what's taking up the memory?

Comment: What I also don't get is why you have 4 nested loops and inside check the object values again? Why don't you first sort the objects if you need to store them in order and do without all those inner loops?

Comment: I have to  store data in format like col -->year,month,zip,Object.object contains all details eg.-2016,5,411001,OBJ

Comment: It seems as if `objlistdata` already contains all that data already, so why the loops?

Comment: I want to store data month wise like Jan-411001-and all data for 411001 in jan in Object

Comment: You still can do that by sorting the objects first then iterating over the sorted list. If you want to aggregate data by year-month-zip then react on any change of those, i.e. if objects at indices 27 and 28 have the same year-month-zip you put them into the same agregate whereas if object at index 29 has a difference there you create a new aggregate.

Comment: Hey,thanks for support.I got it.